# How to execute filter on chain action

Tags: java, filter, struts2

I am facing one issue. Scenario is like:
I have a filter mapping in web.xml as

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.action</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My struts file action mapping as:

```
<action name="index" class="com.test.IndexAction" method="execute">
    <result name="success" type="chain">landing</result>
</action>
```

For now, my filter get called for action index. But I want same filter should get executed for next chain action too.

By changing filter mapping as below, it doesn't work

```
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/index.action</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/landing.action</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

As result type is `chain` the URL from browser does not change to /landing.action

How can I make filter to get executed for next chain action ?

Comment: Why are you using filters at all? Usage of the `chain` result type is discouraged.

Comment: Thank you, but its been already implemented in project, I can't change it. 
I want to make it work for chain only.

Comment: Unless your desired "landing" is on planet mess, in the trouble galaxy, never use `chain` (`dispatcher` and `redirectAction` serves 99% of the cases), and never use *filters* (Struts2 has *Interceptors*, use those). It *can* be changed, if the time you spend to do it right is lower than the time needed to fix it in the hacky way.

Comment: What exactly is already implemented? Filter? Chain? *I can't change it* - of course you can.

Comment: Could you post complete `web.xml`?